# decode cyrillic base64 in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a `base64` encoded JSON string from JavaScript with a part Cyrillic text. I send this to the server and want to decode the `base64`, but this gives me a strange result.

String:

```
    eyJuYW1lT3JkZXIiOlsicHJvcGVydHlpZCIsInByb2plY3RuYW1lIiwiZW52aXJvbm1lbnQiLCJ2YXJpYWJsZSIsInZhbHVlIiwiY29tcG9uZW50IiwidXNhZ2UiLCJhY2Nlc3N0eXBlIiwidmVyc2lvbiIsImxhbmd1YWdlIl0sInBhcmFtZXRlcnMiOlsiNjg1IiwiRGVtbyIsInByb2QiLCJsYWkiLCJ2YWx1ZdCG0L3QtNC10LrRgSDQm9C40YHRgtC+0LLQvtGXINCf0L7QstC10YDRhdC90ZYgKC0pIiwiVHJhbnNsYXRpb24iLCJOT1RUUkFOU0xBVEVEIiwid3JpdGUiLCIwLjQuMCIsInVrIl19
```

I generate this string as follows:

`btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(`array`))))`

Expected result:

```
{  
   "nameOrder":[  
      "propertyid",
      "projectname",
      "environment",
      "variable",
      "value",
      "component",
      "usage",
      "accesstype",
      "version",
      "language"
   ],
   "parameters":[  
      "685",
      "Demo",
      "prod",
      "lai",
      "valueІндекс Листової Поверхні (-)",
      "Translation",
      "NOTTRANSLATED",
      "write",
      "0.4.0",
      "uk"
   ]
}
```

Result (normal `base64_decode` function):

```
{"nameOrder":
[    "propertyid",
     "projectname",
     "environment",
     "variable",
     "value",
     "component",
     "usage",
     "accesstype",
     "version",
     "language"
 ],
 "parameters":
 [   "685",
     "Demo",
     "prod",
     "lai",
     "valueІндекс Листд,ԯեȴ'��ԭt`4at/teȊJHˈ՜ٛݛ][ۈˈӓՕѓՓUQˈޜ۝Hˈ̋͋̈ˈޚȗ_
```

Okay, I found something!
When i use `$_GET` to get the string from the url, it changes. I think this is the problem. What can i do to get the right string from the url?

Comment: Works well when browser encoding is set to utf-8.

Comment: But i don't show the result in the browser, i only send it to the server so i can process it. There it isn't processed in utf-8 apperently.

Comment: You didn't mention any further processing in your question. Since your sample string can be decoded validly in my environment, pls. expand your question to the actual problem.

Comment: The processing isn't working because the json can't be decoded. As soon as the json can be decoded, the processing will work again. Because the browser isn't doing anything, setting the encoding of the browser to utf-8 probably won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR - the encoded data is fine, you're just displaying it in a context that isn't expecting UTF-8.

When dealing with encoding problems, I find it's useful to have a firm grasp of how the encoding works so you can drill down into a hex dump to eliminate any possibility of mis-configured output....

So, here's a dump of the base64 decoded data

```
00000000  7b 22 6e 61 6d 65 4f 72  64 65 72 22 3a 5b 22 70  |{"nameOrder":["p|
00000010  72 6f 70 65 72 74 79 69  64 22 2c 22 70 72 6f 6a  |ropertyid","proj|
00000020  65 63 74 6e 61 6d 65 22  2c 22 65 6e 76 69 72 6f  |ectname","enviro|
00000030  6e 6d 65 6e 74 22 2c 22  76 61 72 69 61 62 6c 65  |nment","variable|
00000040  22 2c 22 76 61 6c 75 65  22 2c 22 63 6f 6d 70 6f  |","value","compo|
00000050  6e 65 6e 74 22 2c 22 75  73 61 67 65 22 2c 22 61  |nent","usage","a|
00000060  63 63 65 73 73 74 79 70  65 22 2c 22 76 65 72 73  |ccesstype","vers|
00000070  69 6f 6e 22 2c 22 6c 61  6e 67 75 61 67 65 22 5d  |ion","language"]|
00000080  2c 22 70 61 72 61 6d 65  74 65 72 73 22 3a 5b 22  |,"parameters":["|
00000090  36 38 35 22 2c 22 44 65  6d 6f 22 2c 22 70 72 6f  |685","Demo","pro|
000000a0  64 22 2c 22 6c 61 69 22  2c 22 76 61 6c 75 65 d0  |d","lai","value.|
000000b0  86 d0 bd d0 b4 d0 b5 d0  ba d1 81 20 d0 9b d0 b8  |........... ....|
000000c0  d1 81 d1 82 d0 be d0 b2  d0 be d1 97 20 d0 9f d0  |............ ...|
000000d0  be d0 b2 d0 b5 d1 80 d1  85 d0 bd d1 96 20 28 2d  |............. (-|
000000e0  29 22 2c 22 54 72 61 6e  73 6c 61 74 69 6f 6e 22  |)","Translation"|
000000f0  2c 22 4e 4f 54 54 52 41  4e 53 4c 41 54 45 44 22  |,"NOTTRANSLATED"|
00000100  2c 22 77 72 69 74 65 22  2c 22 30 2e 34 2e 30 22  |,"write","0.4.0"|
00000110  2c 22 75 6b 22 5d 7d                              |,"uk"]}|
00000117
```

Let's decode the sequence after the word `value` - it looks like valid UTF-8. So we can break it apart in these encoded characters

```
d0 86
d0 bd 
d0 b4 
d0 b5 
d0 ba 
d1 81 
20 
d0 9b 
d0 b8 
d1 81 
d1 82 
d0 be 
d0 b2 
d0 be 
d1 97 
20 
d0 9f 
d0 be 
d0 b2 
d0 b5 
d1 80 
d1 85 
d0 bd 
d1 96 
20 
28 
2d
29
```

Just taking the first one as a sanity check, the sequence `d0 86` in binary is `1101 0000 1000 0110` - that's a valid [UTF-8 2 byte sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) as the first byte starts with `110`, and the second byte starts with `10` - from the rest of the digits we can extract the binary value `100 0000 0110` or `0x406` - that's a [Cyrllic character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/406/index.htm)

So it looks good. And, as it turns out, it is good! If I json_decode that in php, and var_dump the resulting data in a console set up for UTF-8, it looks good to me.

So everything is fine - you're displaying the data somewhere which isn't expecting UTF-8 encoded text.

Comment: Thats strange, because when i test the encoded string on https://www.base64decode.org it gives me the exact result i want.

Comment: Actually, I've misread the problem, and thought the JSON was broken - that really is what you're supposed to have - the encoding of that cyrillic string must be broken in other ways...

Comment: I added the way i encode the array (first to json string and then to url encoding, unescaping and finally to base64). Can i do this in a better way?

Comment: Updated answer - it's all good, you're just displaying the decoded JSON data somewhere which doesn't understand UTF-8

Comment: I'm not displaying the decoded json data. I process it on the server itself in php. When i try to use `utf8_encode` the result stays the same. In your answer you tried the first combination of the cyrillic character. But it doesn't go wrong on the first character, but on the 12th.

Comment: Probably found the reason for the error: The `$_GET` isn't returning the same string as there is in the url. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Made sure query string arguments are properly encoded - looking at the code you supplied, you've got things in an odd order. You probably want something like `encodeURIComponent(btoa(JSON.stringify(array)))`

Answer (score 0):

I have that encoded string :

```
eyJuYW1lT3JkZXIiOlsicHJvcGVydHlpZCIsInByb2plY3RuYW1lIiwiZW52aXJvbm1lbnQiLCJ2YXJpYWJsZSIsInZhbHVlIiwiY29tcG9uZW50IiwidXNhZ2UiLCJhY2Nlc3N0eXBlIiwidmVyc2lvbiIsImxhbmd1YWdlIl0sInBhcmFtZXRlcnMiOlsiNjg1IiwiRGVtbyIsInByb2QiLCJsYWkiLCJ2YWx1ZdCG0L3QtNC10LrRgSDQm9C40YHRgtC+0LLQvtGXINCf0L7QstC10YDRhdC90ZYgKC0pIiwiVHJhbnNsYXRpb24iLCJOT1RUUkFOU0xBVEVEIiwid3JpdGUiLCIwLjQuMCIsInVrIl19Cg==
```

Maybe you hade a trouble with your encoding ? I used base64 from bash.
I'm sorry I can't say why the encoding failed (maybe a parse error ?)

Comment: I'm sending the encoded string via a GET to the server, so possibly this is the reason why it is different?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. It is like Paul Dixon said in his last comment.
The string I used encoded to a string in which a plus-sign is included. The querystring deleted this out of the querystring and the decoding didn't go as it should.